# Переменные, static, глобальные

Tags: java, терминология

> Переменные экземпляра, объявленные как static, по существу, являются глобальными.

Как это понять?

Comment: К этим полям можно получить доступ без создания объекта класса. Поэтому можно сказать что они "глобальные". Но они могут быть private, а это уже не глобальное поле ибо доступа к ней нет окромя как внутри класса.

Comment: И опять плохая формулировка. В Java нет глобальных переменных, а рассматривать статические поля в этой роли можно только с ооочень большой натяжкой и множеством оговорок. Что у вас за источник?

Comment: @SergeyGornostaev Шилдт руководство для начинающих

Comment: 0_0 Сомневаюсь, что Шилдт сошёл с ума на старости лет, он всегда был толковым автором, видать, огрехи перевода.

Comment: Предполагаю, имеется виду то, что статические поля класса являются общими для всех экземпляров этого класса.

Comment: @SergeyGornostaev Какие книги на русском посоветуете прочитать по джаве, где нормальный перевод?

Comment: Сложный для меня вопрос, так как я учился очень давно. Вроде неплохой перевод у "Изучаем Java" Кэти Сиерры и Берта Бейтса. В тексте есть опечатки, но не критичные. К тому же серия Head First очень хороша для новичков своей доходчивостью.

Comment: Хорошим примером являются переменные ``Math.E``  и ``Math.PI``, которые можно использовать в любом месте не создавая никаких объектов. В этом смысле ``Math.E``  и ``Math.PI`` можно рассматривать как глобальные переменные.

Comment: Книжка у Шилдта довольно посредственная и мало выделяется среди прочего моря макулатуры. Из действительно хороших можно посоветовать Брюс Эккель "Философия Java" - одна из немногих, где упор делается на понимание языка. а не на тупое перечисление синтаксических конструкций.

Answer (score 1):

Переменная экземпляра - это поле класса. Чтобы её использовать нужно создать экземпляр класса, причём у каждого экземпляра класса это поле своё. Но если это поле объявлено как static, то получается что это поле (переменная) одна для ВСЕХ экземпляров класса, и её можно использовать без создания экземпляра класса.

```
Class A {
    public int a;
}

Class B {
    public static int b;
}

Class Main {
    public static void main (String args[]) {
        A newA = new A();
        System.out.println(newA.a); //чтобы использовать переменную a класса A пришлось 
                                    //создать экземпляр класса newA

        System.out.println(B.b);    //Чтобы использовать переменную b класса B нам не 
                                    //нужно создавать для этого экземпляр класса
    }
}
```